# Why can't I use loop 'for i in...' in a definition? (Local Variable i not used)

Tags: python, for-loop, pycharm, local-variables

I'm new with Python and coding, doing some exercises online.

I am writing a class for making lists of random numbers:

```
class RandomList:
    def create_list(self):
        self.list = []
    def fill_list(self, min, max, range):
        self.list = [random.randint(min, max) for i in range(range)]
```

First of all --> 
I do not understand the Pycharm warning message under `self.list = []` 
telling me:

> "Instance attribute list is defined outside **init**"

What would be the difference if I wrote:

```
class RandomList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []
```

Secondly --> 
The fill_list function doesn't work when I call `RandomList.fill_list`:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.

And there is a warning message under  'i':

> Local Variable not used

I don't understand why

I am at loss here because when I use for example:

```
a = [random.randint(min, max) for i in range(range)]
```

outside of the class there is no issue whatsoever. I think I must be mixing things up here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: You can not use variable names with min, max, range

Example:

```py
range = 4
for i in range(range): #you will get error
    print("Hello!")
```

Your code should be

```py
class RandomList:
    def create_list(self):
        self.list = []
    def fill_list(self, minnum, maxnum, rangenum):
        self.list = [random.randint(minnum, maxnum) for i in range(rangenum)]
```

And you can test it with

```py
randlist = RandomList
randlist.create_list(randlist)
randlist.fill_list(randlist, 1, 5, 3)

print(randlist.list) #prints randomly like [1, 4, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer -
How come do you need to pass 'randList' as an paremeter, somehow I thought Python understood the 'self' itself (no pun intended)


Also, just wondering how python knows what .list is in 

      `print(randlist.list)`

thanks again :)

Comment: ```randlist.create_list``` is a function and can not detect randList is a variable. Example, if you create a class named "testList" and define a empty list named "list" in it. You can use the "fill_list" function with it. You can ```RandomList.fill_list(testList, 1, 5, 3)``` and you can take your list with ```mylist = testList.list``` and print it with ```print(mylist)```

Comment: Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3):

1. It's a PEP8 convention to only initialize instance attributes inside `__init__`. Otherwise the code becomes a mess to follow and debug, especially for people who did not write it.
2. You get the warning that `i` is not used because, well, you don't use it. Use `_` which is the de-facto standard for throw-away variables, or use `self.list = [random.randint(min, max)] * range`, but `range` is a bad variable name (so are 'min' and 'max'), see point 3.
3. You get the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.` because you override the build in `range` with the `range` argument in your method. `min` and `max` are also built-in functions and should not be used for variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Here (`range` is a reserved word)

```
import random 
class RandomList:
    def __init__(self, min, max, _range):
        self.lst = [random.randint(min, max) for i in range(_range)]

rl = RandomList(4,7,10)
print(rl.lst)
```

output

```
[5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 4, 4, 6, 7, 6]
```

Comment: `range` is a built-in class, not a reserved word (if it was reserved then you would not have been able to override it so easily)